# Rearranging Columns in Pandas then Concatenate

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I scraped data for NBA games that contains both the main team and their opponent.

The first dataframe (Team) is fine.

I want to duplicate the data then make the same dataframe but for the opponent as the main team.

Here are the column names, In order to make the second duplicated dataframe everything with a t goes to o and everything with an o becomes a t (O=opponent, T=Team)

```
['Opponent_x','O1q_x','O2q_x','O3q_x','O4q_x','Oot','Ofinal_x', 'Team_x','T1q_x', 'T2q_x','T3q_x','T4q_x','Tot','Tfinal_x']

Opponent=['Wizards','25','23','33','22','0','103','Celtics','23','20', '27','32','0','102']
Team=['Celtics','23','20','27','32','0','102''Wizards','25','23', '33','22','0','103']
```

End result should be

```
['Wizards','25','23','33','22','0','103','Celtics','23','20', '27','32','0','102']
['Celtics','23','20','27','32','0','102''Wizards','25','23', '33','22','0','103']
```

So i have tried

```
Opponent.columns =['Team_x','T1q_x','T2q_x','T3q_x','T4q_x','Tot','Tfinal_x','Opponent_x', 'O1q_x','O2q_x','O3q_x','O4q_x','Oot','Ofinal_x']

All = pd.concat(Opponent,Team)
```

this does not give the correct dimensions and some of the data didnt move to the right place

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output to this question?

Comment: added example data

Answer (score 0):

Start with creation of a "shaddow" DataFrame, with "switched halves" of columns:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, 7:14], df.iloc[:, 0:7]], axis=1)
```

Then overwrite column names (in *df2*) with original columns:

```
df2.columns = df.columns
```

And get the final result concatenating these two:

```
result = pd.concat([df, df2])
```

Maybe finally you should also change column names in *result* to something
other than *Team_...* and *Opponent_...*, e.g. to *Team1_...* and  *Team2_...*
(your choice).

Answer (score 0):

Find integer location of `Team_x` in the columns. Use this number with `np.roll` to roll columns of `Team` to the left and `reindex` and reassign columns.

```
df_team:

  Opponent_x O1q_x O2q_x O3q_x O4q_x Oot Ofinal_x   Team_x T1q_x T2q_x T3q_x  \
0    Celtics    23    20    27    32   0      102  Wizards    25    23    33

  T4q_x Tot Tfinal_x
0    22   0      103


n = df_team.columns.get_loc('Team_x')
df_opponent = df_team.reindex(np.roll(df_team.columns, 7), axis=1)
df_opponent.columns = df_team.columns

print(df_opponent)

Out[23]:
  Opponent_x O1q_x O2q_x O3q_x O4q_x Oot Ofinal_x   Team_x T1q_x T2q_x T3q_x  \
0    Wizards    25    23    33    22   0      103  Celtics    23    20    27

  T4q_x Tot Tfinal_x
0    32   0      102
```